# magento promotion product import?

Tags: magento

I have a magento shop with ~30 000 products. I also have a csv file of ~5000 existing products with a structure like this:

```
SKU,TermsCategory,QuantityBreak,StartDate,EndDate,NettSellPrice,SellDiscount1,SellDiscount3,RebateFlag,PromotionNumber,PromotionName,PromotionType
"ZARSP500","0",2,01102011,31122011,710,0,0,"N",9907,"Hand Tool Bulk Buy","B"
```

Is it possible to somehow import all that as a temporary promotion?

EDIT: By "Promotion" I meant in magento "Catalog Price Rules" under "Promotion", unless there is any other way to change prices for specific period of time.

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague.  What's the behavior are you looking for with "temporary promotion"?

Comment: Lots of people use Tiered Pricing to implement promotional pricing, as well as the "special price" field in products.  It's important to remember there's multiple ways to do things in Magento, and the more specific you are the better chance someone will answer you here.

Answer (score 0):

You could import lots of 'Special Price' using the dataflow, but getting the quantity 'tier' prices on that would be tricky.

I recommend that you write new promo rules in Magento to do whatever it is that whomever created the 30000 spreadsheet hopes to achieve. Then test them.